# "We walked around with Joe" or "I walked around with Joe"

Tags: word-choice, usage

I was out with a friend today (only me and him), and I told my girlfriend that "***we walked around with Joe***", and she asked me who else was there besides Joe. When I told her that it was only me and Joe, she said that I should have said "***I walked around with Joe***".

When I say "We walked around with Joe.", does it imply that there was more than one person with me?

Comment: Unless you’re Queen Elizabeth or you have a mouse in your pocket, yes, ***we*** means there’s more of you there than just a single person.

Comment: We means there's more than one person, but I meant it was me an Joe. She said that when I said "We walked around with Joe." it means there was me, Joe, and at least one more person. Is that so? And I'm not a native speaker that's why I'm asking this.

Comment: Yes, she is right about that. For that matter, it would be true in any of a dozen-odd other European languages; what language does not work this way?

Comment: hattenn, I invite you to visit the English Language Learners StackExchange site, too, where answers are aimed at the needs of learners. Many people, both askers and answerers, are active on both sites. If you think ELL would be better for this question, click on the flag link above and ask that a moderator migrate it.

Comment: @Carlo_R., thanks for letting me know. I wasn't aware that there was an English Language Learners SE. I'll flag it right away.

Comment: "We means there's more than one person, but I meant it was me and Joe." *We* refers to the people who walked around *with* Joe. So unless Joe walked around with himself, or you had a double there, there was only *one person* walking *with* Joe.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem is caused by me confusing it with my native language. When you literally translate "We walked around with Joe." to my mother tongue, it makes complete sense (it means it was just me and Joe). It apparently isn't the same in English.

Comment: What language is it?

Comment: @MετάEd, Turkish.

Comment: Oh, then merhaba!

Comment: If you omit "with Joe," then you can say "We walked around," which does not imply that there was a third person.

Comment: Interestingly, the reason that Queen Elizabeth might refer to herself as "we" is for the same reason that someone might call Henry VII "England", that being that the ruler is considered the embodiment of the spirit of the entire people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"We walked around with Joe" implies that there were at least three people there.  The action in this sentence is "walking around *with* Joe," which Joe is not doing. Joe *is* Joe. Joe is not *walking with* Joe. The subject of the sentence is whoever is doing the action. Since Joe is not doing the action, he is not included as a subject of the sentence. The only subject is you, so the correct sentence is, "I walked around with Joe."